# Struct, Iterate over, C++

Tags: c++, iterator, range

Suppose I have a simple `struct Range` as follows

```
template<typename T>
struct Range {
    T min;
    T max;

    Range(T min, T max) : min(min), max(max) {}

    Range() {}


};
```

As you may see my range struct represents a simple range for any type.
Now I want to write a code like this

```
int main() {
    Range<int> range(0,100);
    for(const auto& elem : range){
        std::cout<<elem<<" "; \\ Shall print numbers from 0 to 100;
    }
}
```

I know I have to provide implementation of `cbegin()` , `cend()`, `begin()` and `end()` in my struct for this to compile. But how shall I implement them to actually print these numbers?

Please note that `sizeof(Range)` must not change.

UPDATE:
For floating point numbers to iterate one must specify the step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217541/how-to-create-a-range-like-iterable-object-of-floats

Comment: Definitely, thanks, you can mark as similar.